# React for functional widgets in a CMS page (.Net website), Is this a React bad practice?

Tags: .net, reactjs

I am new to react and still learning, awesome library and kudos to FB.

I have to build a website with .Net Based Enterprise CMS and I don't want to detach the whole View layer from the CMS for a few reasons.

Most of the site is static with some personalisation, but there are couple of elements in the site which requires updating or we can call them functional widgets.

They gets updated based on user input. e.g think of a calculator widget on a page or graphs and charts which changes based on input data.

Can I built this widgets in React or building just a part of the page is a bad practice,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely build small pieces of interactivity using React. Whether it's worth the cost of the framework depends on how interactive these pieces are. If they're small things then I would just use some vanilla js to add that functionality. If they truly are little mini apps embedded in the page then the decision sways more towards using React or some other framework.